# How to get access token from Yammer without user login?

Tags: php, laravel, yammer

**Here is Yammer Docs:** https://developer.yammer.com/

When I try to make a request via browser, successfully I'm able to get access token
https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[:client_id]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri]

However I must do it programmatically. So While my API is making a request to any endpoint of Yammer, should generate a new access token if access token expires. But I came across the following screenshot:
[image: here is screenshot]

I think about headers of my request. I've added some headers (user agent)

```
    public function getCode(Request $request)
{
    $code = $request->get('code');

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    if (!is_null($code)) {
        $res = $client->request(
          'GET',
          'https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id='.$this->clientId.'&client_secret='.$this->clientSecret.'&code='.$code
        );
        echo $res->getBody();
    }else {
        $res = $client->request(
          'GET',
          'https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id='.$this->clientId.'&response_type=code&redirect_uri='.$this->redirectUri,
          [
              'headers' => [
                  'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
              ]
          ]
        );

        echo $res->getBody();
    }
}
```

**P.S:** redirect uri was the same action for my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

After making a request try the below code instead of  echo $res->getBody();

```
$response =json_decode($res->getBody(), true);
return $response;
```